# Google Api key location and address solution

Tags: api, google-maps, postal-code, google-location-services

I am developing a mobile app and website that allow users to advertise their items only in the UK. However, I don't want the return address to show the full address of the seller on the advert but instead should show the town and the city

For example, **395 Frances Street, London, SE18 5JU, England, UK**. This address is in Greenwich town. I just want the location on the advert to show only the town and the city. For example **(Greenwich, London)**

I mean I would like to restrict the address not to show the full address but specific town and city. Please what is the best solution and how do I achieve this. any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding) if you have the street address and check the "address_components" in the response or use the Places API to request [**Address Components**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-data-fields#basic) about the place (`Place.Field.ADDRESS_COMPONENTS` if using the Places SDK for Android and `GMSPlaceFieldAddressComponents` if using the Places SDK for iOS). Both will return the address broken into components so you can select which components to display. Each component type is explained in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding#Types) though it may take some experimentation to know which `administrative_area_level_N` corresponds to the concepts of "town" and "city" in your area.